# CiviContribute Donation Form error

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, authorize.net

Everything was working fine for weeks (civicrm on drupal) then this error on the civicontribute form web page:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   CRM_Core_Payment_Manual::setBackOffice() in
>   /var/www/html/missional/donations/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/Form.php
>   on line 67

And these errors on the log in page:

> Notice: Undefined index: user_name in
>   CRM_Core_Payment_AuthorizeNet->__construct() (line 56 of
>   /var/www/html/missional/donations/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/AuthorizeNet.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   CRM_Core_Payment_AuthorizeNet->__construct() (line 57 of
>   /var/www/html/missional/donations/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/AuthorizeNet.php).

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you explain more what might have happen in those weeks? E.g did you update your site? Did you install a new extension or module?

Answer (score 2):

We fixed this on https://chat.civicrm.org.

The latest versions of the [Authorize.net eCheck payment processor extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/authorizenet-echecknet) (versions 1.2 to 1.2.2) break CiviCRM (the problem exists as far back as 4.7.23, probably further).

The solution for now is to disable the eCheck extension.  The author of the extension (or someone else - it's open source!) will need to fix the problem with the extension.